# Querydsl in RavenDB 4

Tags: java, maven, querydsl, ravendb4

Updating to RavenDB 4 seems to have broken the Maven setup for querydsl. This no longer seems to work:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                    <processor>net.ravendb.querydsl.RavenDBAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    <options>
                        <querydsl.entityAccessors>true</querydsl.entityAccessors>
                    </options>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

It no longer recognizes the @QueryEntity tag.
I have gone through the 4.0 documentation, but couldn't find anything... Thanks for any pointers to get this fixed.

Regards

Comment: Besides this issue, I think that - certainly for the Java client - 4.0 isn't quite there yet. Just realised that almost no documentation exists for the Java side of things; perhaps I'll hold off on the migration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryDSL is not supported in RavenDB v4.0 client as of now.

https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.ravendb%7Cravendb%7C4.0.0%7Cjar

Documentation is in progress. In meanwhile you can use c# client documentation as Java Client is very similar to c# client (except linq and some of features which are not yet present).

Comment: thanks for confirming. Any idea on the support of QueryDSL timeline ? Q2/3 perhaps ? That'd be wonderful. And don't get me wrong: RavenDB is fantastic. I'm a Fan :-)

Comment: It is in the queue, but it is hard for me to estimate exact date.